# Cassandra ReadTimeout when querying existing data

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

For my test server, I have no-replication Cassandra 2.1.6 setup:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE v2 WITH replication =
{'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'} AND durable_writes = false;

CREATE TABLE v2.tiles (
    zoom int,
    idx int,
    tile blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (zoom, idx)
)
```

For each zoom value, there could be tens of millions of small items.  For zoom=11, the first idx is in around 100352. When I need to iterate over all items, I allways see this time out error for specific storage cases:

```
cqlsh:v2> select zoom,idx from tiles where zoom=11 limit 10;
ReadTimeout: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

I get the same error for "zoom=11 and idx > 1000".
For idx value closer to the existing items, it gives the right result:

```
cqlsh:v2> select zoom,idx from tiles where zoom=11 and idx > 100000 limit 10;
 zoom | idx
------+--------
   11 | 100352
...
```

It also shows correct empty results when idx is compared with extremelly high value:

```
cqlsh:v2> select zoom,idx from tiles where zoom=11 and idx > 1000000 limit 10;                                       
 zoom | idx | tile
------+-----+------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: You can setup your read time manually in cassandra.conf file . Partition key can only store 2 billions rows so please make your model according to this condition .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For each zoom value, there could be tens of millions of small items. For zoom=11, the first idx is in around 100352. When I need to iterate over all items, I always see this time out error for specific storage cases.

This sounds like a wide row row issue.  When you have many items for a single partition (zoom in your case) it can create problems for reads in cassandra.  In general it's a good rule of thumb to keep partitions at < 100MB in size, do you think you may have partitions that large?  On average how many bytes is the 'tile' column?    For example, with idx being a 4-byte int, and lets assume a blob size of 96 bytes, giving 100 bytes per row and ignoring any overhead ~1,048,576 rows would equal 100MB

Although your page size in small, there is still is quite a bit of overhead on cassandra's end to read the data and its indexes on disk.  What seems to happening is your C* node is not able to read the data within [read_request_timeout_in_ms](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__read_request_timeout_in_ms) (default is 10s).  When your queries **do work** about how long are they taking?

It may be worth enabling tracing ('TRACING ON' in a cqlsh session) to help understand what is taking so long when your queries do succeed.  You could also consider increasing read_request_timeout_in_ms to some arbitrarily large value while debugging.  A good article on tracing can be found [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2).

If you find that your rows are too wide, you may consider partitioning your data further, for example by day:

```
CREATE TABLE v2.tiles (
    zoom int,
    day timestamp,
    idx int,
    tile blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((zoom, day), idx)
)
```

Although without knowing more about your data model, time might not be a good way of partitioning.

Comment: Thanks Andy for a thorough reply! I think I would have to break it up using fake partition:  ((zoom, idxHigh), idxLow), where idxHigh = idx / 10000, and idxLow = idx % 10000. See trace at https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/P1289

Comment: Hrmm, that doesn't seem great, but not too bad (459ms).  It does seem suspect however that there is 267ms of delay between 'merging sstable tombstones' and 'Key cache hit for sstable 11'.   Have you by chance deleted a lot of data (guessing not)?  Can you show me what a trace looks like for 'select zoom,idx from tiles where zoom=11 and idx > 200000 limit 2;', > 100000, > 500000 and so on?  Will be interesting to see if the query gets slower as you reduce the idx.

Comment: Thx, re-posted new data to the same link. Also, the idx>0 now started to working after a long wait (~9s).  I have recently dropped a keyspace and re-created it, and there is some active writing going on to a different keyspace on the same server.

Comment: Ah, I missed your statement about partitioning on idxHigh.  That should  work pretty good if that matches your query patterns well :)

Comment: Come to think of it, I should probably not cluster the partition:  PRIMARY KEY (zoom, idxHi, idxLo), with some constant divider, e.g. 10000

Comment: I don't see anything longer than a second in your recent traces, is that just because you've dropped the keyspace and started writing new data?

Comment: Andy, I have seen this behavior on several servers under different configuration, even without the deletion.  I ran the query about 20 min ago, and it gave me the result. After seeing your comment, I re-ran it, and got a timeout. Doing it again right away showed result after about 15 seconds. See https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/P1296

Comment: interesting, something is not adding up from the traces.  Could you paste the results of: 'select * from system_traces.sessions where session_id=cf2299a0-366b-11e5-bfa9-8da725ce81a6'.  Interested in what the 'duration' column shows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84632/discussion-between-yurik-and-andy-tolbert).

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this error has been resolved increasing the time of parameter "range_request_timeout_in_ms" in "cassandra.yaml" file. By default, the value of this parameter is 10000 ms.